# translate-pathname behaves strange

Tags: common-lisp

Following this question: [Strange symbols in filespec when calling load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661617/strange-symbols-in-filespec-when-calling-load) I tried my luck with pathnames, but, as you see, failed. Below is an example of the error, which I cannot explain:

This code does not work:

```
(defun test-process-imgae-raw ()
  (cl-gd:with-image-from-file
      (test #P"digit-recognition:digit-7.png")
    (process-image-raw test)))
```

Neither does this:

```
(defun test-process-imgae-raw ()
  (cl-gd:with-image-from-file
      (test "digit-recognition:digit-7.png")
    (process-image-raw test)))
```

But this code does:

```
(defun test-process-imgae-raw ()
  (cl-gd:with-image-from-file
      (test (translate-logical-pathname "digit-recognition:digit-7.png"))
    (process-image-raw test)))
```

And so does this:

```
(defun test-process-imgae-raw ()
  (cl-gd:with-image-from-file
      (test (translate-logical-pathname #P"digit-recognition:digit-7.png"))
    (process-image-raw test)))
```

Here's the "translator":

```
(setf (logical-pathname-translations "DIGIT-RECOGNITION")
      `(("**;*.*" "/home/wvxvw/Projects/digit-recognition/**/*.*")))
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Pathname components from SOURCE and FROM args to TRANSLATE-PATHNAME
did not match:
  :NEWEST NIL
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] Abort thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1003800113}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-IMPL::DIDNT-MATCH-ERROR :NEWEST NIL)
  1: (SB-IMPL::TRANSLATE-COMPONENT :NEWEST NIL :NEWEST T)
  2: (TRANSLATE-PATHNAME #P"DIGIT-RECOGNITION:DIGIT-7.PNG.NEWEST" #P"DIGIT-RECOGNITION:**;*.*" #P"/home/wvxvw/Projects/digit-recognition/**/*.*")
  3: (TRANSLATE-LOGICAL-PATHNAME #P"DIGIT-RECOGNITION:DIGIT-7.PNG.NEWEST")
  4: (SB-IMPL::QUERY-FILE-SYSTEM #P"DIGIT-RECOGNITION:DIGIT-7.PNG" :TRUENAME NIL)
  5: (PROBE-FILE #P"DIGIT-RECOGNITION:DIGIT-7.PNG")
  6: (CREATE-IMAGE-FROM-FILE #<unavailable argument> NIL)
  7: (TEST-PROCESS-IMGAE-RAW)
```

I'm trying to read the Hyperspec section on translate-pathname, but I can make absolutely no sense of what it says, neither from the examples it shows. Let alone it, I can't even understand how there can possibly be an error if you transform a string by whatever rules you put in place, so far it's only one way transformation...

I'm trying to read SBCL sources for this function, but they are really lengthy, and trying to figure out the problem this way is taking huge amounts of time.

**tl;dr** How is it even possible that `translate-logical-pathname` called from user's code will produce something different to what is produced from that function if called from system code? This is not only non-portable, this is just outright broken.

**EDIT:**

Adding one more asterisk to the pattern on the left side, but not on the right solved this. But the purpose or logic of why is this necessary is beyond me.

I.e.

```
(setf (logical-pathname-translations "DIGIT-RECOGNITION")
      `(("**;*.*.*" "/home/wvxvw/Projects/digit-recognition/**/*.*")))
```

This allows pathnames like `digit-recognition:foo.bar.newest` to succeed, just like `digit-recognition:foo.bar` but why is that asterisk a requirement flies beyond me. Also, why is the system function feels entitled to change the pathname to something else of what it was given?.. But just not to get you confused, `with-image-from-file` will only work with the path already expanded by `translate-logical-pathname`, it won't work otherwise.

**EDIT2:**

OK, it seems like this is the problem with `cl-gd`, instead of trying to expand the file name, it takes it literally. This code taken from `create-image-from-file` probably best answers my question:

```
(when (pathnamep file-name)
  (setq file-name
          #+:cmu (ext:unix-namestring file-name)
          #-:cmu (namestring file-name)))
(with-foreign-object (err :int)
  (with-cstring (c-file-name file-name)
    (let ((image (ecase %type
                   ((:jpg :jpeg)
                     (gd-image-create-from-jpeg-file c-file-name err))
```

I.e. instead of doing `(namestring file-name)` it has to do `(namestring (trnaslate-logical-pathname file-name))`. Duh...

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `TRUENAME`, which returns the real file name. Normally this would not make a difference.

Image a file system with file versions (like the file systems of VMS, ...). If you have a logical pathname `foo:bar;baz.png.newest`, then it might translate to, say, `/myfiles/images/baz.png~newest` (again, just assume that it has version numbers). This still is not a real physical file. If such a Lisp system tries to open the file, it has to look into the file system to actually determine the newest file. That might be `/myfiles/images/baz.png~42`.

So, if you want to pass real physical filenames to external tools (like a C library), it might not be sufficient to expand the logical pathname, but it might be necessary to compute the *truename* - the real physical file.

The ability to deal with file versions comes from a time when file versions where quite common (see [Versioning file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system)) with operating systems like ITS, VMS or the various Lisp Machine operating systems.

The main practical problem for this is that there is no common test suite for pathname operations for the various CL implementations and thus implementations differ in a lot of subtle details (especially when you need to deal with different file systems from different operating systems). Plus real file systems have complications - for example file names in Mac OS X use a special unicode encoding when dealing with Umlauts.

Comment: @wvxvw: some function (for example `PROBE-FILE`) might add a version component to the end. Then `*.*` might not match, but `*.*.*`.